# Why does QtCreator not show the 'Applications' section on Mac?

Tags: macos, qt-creator

The lists of templates differ. For example when I load the tutorial "Creating a Qt Widget Based Application", it shows the following screenshot.

[image: QtCreator should look like this]

"Applications" is clearly a visible section of templates available on the left.

I've just downloaded Qt Creator 2.8.1 for Mac (53 MB) from http://qt-project.org/downloads and when I run it I see:

[image: What QtCreator looks like when I run it]

What's going on? I can't even get a simple project started.

Comment: I'm suspecting that I'll have to get the QtLibraries as well, but I really want to avoid the large download if at all possible... I'm only  using QtCreator for developing my user interface for PySide!